# Visual Studio 2012: cl.exe -1073741701 on x86 only

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Professional updated to SP5 under Windows 7 SP1 with latest updates.
I needed Visual Studio 2015 for some time, installed then uninstalled it with standard uninstaller.

But today I needed to build Webkit for Windows, and its build script ran `vswhere.exe` and detected some parts from Visual Studio 2015 as "working" installation, so I needed "full" uninstall for VS2015, which I found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller.
I ran it once, and VS2015 disappeared from `vswhere.exe` output.

But now I have a problem:
Every app I trying to compile with VS2012 gives "cl.exe terminated abnormally with code -1073741701".

I tried :

- Reinstalled VS2012 with or without SP5 multiple times, including clean reinstall (uninstall main, uninstall dependencies, install again), still same error.
- Tried to repair VS2012.
- I tried to run `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\cl.exe`, it says "mspdb110.dll not found".
- I copied
  `Msobj110.dll`,
  `Mspdb110.dll`,
  `Mspdbcore.dll` and
  `Mspdbsrv.exe`
  from
  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE`
  and added to the PATH
  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE`. Still same error.

If I switch project platform to x64, it compiles and runs without a problem. Only x86 compiler cannot run and gives the error above. Sometimes there is a popup in VS2012 that "cl.exe cannot run code 0xc000007b".

If I run
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat x86`,
I can run `cl.exe` and even compile working 32-bit apps, but inside Visual Studio 2012 IDE it fails to run `cl.exe` every time, no matter what I do.

Please help me to fix it.

I think maybe it's something to do with .NET Framework (I have 4.5, 4.6 and 4.7 installed) in the `MSBuild` folder. Maybe I need to reinstall .NET Framework SDK somehow? If possible, I want to avoid reinstalling OS.

EDIT:
Started a bounty. Still have a same problem.

I tried to insert run `cl.exe` without parameters in "Run before build..." script, and it runs from there! But afterward the IDE runs `cl.exe` from .NET environment and gives:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(347,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" terminated error code -1073741701

If I select x64 platform, `cl.exe` runs everywhere perfectly fine.
If I run `vcvarsall.bat x86`, I can run `cl.exe` and compile.

The only thing I need to fix is some path in environment which used for Win32 x86 build from Visual Studio 2012 IDE. I can reinstall .NET Framework or Visual Studio (tried it but anyway) or edit some MSBuild configurations. Please tell me where possible to fix. The only thing I cannot do is reinstall OS, as I have a lot of software and reinstall will take a LOT of time.

UPDATE:
Tried to uninstall everything, including .NET Framework 4.5, 4.6, 4.7 and Microsoft SQL Server 2008, 2012. Then installed Visual Studio 2012 Professional RTM. After install on first run I opened test app and got same error as above... 
x64 version works. Same after installing SP5.

UPDATE2:
Tried to bring files of Visual Studio 2012 and Windows SDK and msbuild from working Windows 7 SP1 virtual machine install. It doesn't fix an error, same problem. Also tried to replace cl.exe with dummy 32-bit app, still causes 0xc000007b every time I run build from IDE. Seems like when ran from IDE Visual Studio uses cl.exe 32-bit with some 64-bit DLL. But I don't know how to find it and how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

The risk with uninstalling one Visual Studio version when several are installed,
is to uninstall too much. Visual Studio versions can be installed side-by-side,
but they may use common components.

It seems that this is what happened to you, and your efforts to fix it by copying
DLLs and modifying the PATH have only added to the confusion.
Currently I believe that your PATH and other environment variables cause the
mix-up of 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs, unless you run `vcvarsall.bat` to reset them.

I do not think that I should offer more ideas for further patching of the situation,
as it may only aggravate the problem and leave hidden time-bombs for the future.

This is the closest way for doing a clean install of Visual Studio and .Net
that I can think of :

- Clean-uninstall Visual Studio 2012 Professional using
  [Revo Uninstaller freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html)
- Uninstall all .Net versions that you can from
  Control Panel > Programs and Features, as well as from
  Turn Windows feature on or off
- Scrub all folders and the registry, manually or by running a cleaner such as
  [CCleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner)
- Re-install the .Net version(s) while trying to minimize their number
  (normally you should only need the latest version)
- Install Visual Studio 2012 Professional and update to SP5.

I cannot guarantee success, but this is how I would try to get a really
clean installation and avoid reinstalling Windows.

I suggest taking as backup an image of the system disk, just in case,
so you can go back to it.
I recommend
[AOMEI Backupper Standard](https://www.backup-utility.com/personal.html).

Comment: Thank You for answer. Unfortunately I tried my best to reinstall it all and .NET Framework too. Visual Studio installer doing pretty good and installs .NET Framework with all dependencies and all files. I think the only thing messed up is a path to mspdb110.dll. 32-bit cl.exe somehow tries to load 64-bit dll. There are exactly two mspdb110.dll on my PC, one in IDE folder(32 bit) another in amd64 folder(64-bit). Strange thing is it does it only when ran under IDE from msbuild. My idea is to make dummy cl.exe and check environment it uses. Still don't know where I can change path set by msbuild.

Comment: If you scrub everything real well, the PATH shouldn't be wrong. After total uninstall, verify that there is nothing left in the PATH (but CCleaner should detect that).

Comment: OK, will try it later. Just want to see if there is some easier fix before uninstalling it all and scan. All this for one dll. If nothing will help, and CCleaner will do, +50 is Yours :).

Comment: I understand. Uninstalling or installing Visual Studio is a big pain and redoing it repeatedly is just abysmal.

Comment: Be sure to undo everything you did manually, because the uninstaller will certainly not know about it, and it's not sure that Revo or CCleaner will catch it.

Comment: I tried it (clean uninstall, CCleaner, reinstall, update 5). Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. Thank You anyway! Interesting thing if I put dummy 32-bit exe instead of cl.exe which causes an error, Visual Studio 2012 still gives 0xc000007b like if 32-bit EXE ran with 64-bit dll... If I knew a way to trace which dll, and how to change it I probably can fix. Unfortunately I don't.

Comment: If you know the `.exe` it should be easy tracing the dependencies using the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). If you don't, you may still trace what happens using [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Comment: All in all, I don't think that you have managed to totally undo whatever caused the problem. Clean uninstall plus reinstall should have restored a healthy situation. If the problem was VS2015, perhaps reinstalling it and uninstalling using Revo might help this time for the above procedure to succeed. But all this is taking you many hours and days, so I start doubting whether I really should counsel the clean installation of Windows rather than spending this much time on manipulations that fail, even though this might also be time-consuming.

Comment: Will try to reinstall Visual Studio 2015. I think just install will be enough coz both VS2012 and VS2015 are worked before and after unistall VS2015. Also it will be interesting if VS2015 C++ 32-bit compiler still works.

Comment: Tried it: cl.exe 32-bit from VS2015 works, but gives strange link errors: "LIBCMTD.lib(loadcfg.obj): 3 unresolved symbols: ___guard_fids_table, ___guard_fids_count, ___guard_flags", same in release mode, same with /GS-. Command line build works. 64-bit compilers in 2012, 2015 work. VS2015 update 3 applied, still the same. VS2012 cl.exe 32-bit gives the same error as before VS2015 install. I think I'll give up and reinstall OS later, when I'll find time for it. At least I can compile to 64-bit now.

Comment: VS and .Net are a very complex product and when they go wrong it's not always possible to fix. Personally I avoid uninstalling them, for a good reason, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with VS2015. In my case, deleting the following files from the project folder fixed the problem

```
\.vs\myProjectName\v14\.suo
\myProjectName.VC.db
\x64 (the whole x64 build output folder if there is one)
```

Comment: ...but only because that reset the VC target version of my project. Unfortunately, setting it back to the original version, the problem returned.

Comment: My issue is not about project settings. It occurs always on any new project, and on all projects too. There still can be a way to fix VS installation, but I see noone here knows how.